# What would happen if role blocker blocks role blocker blocking first Role blocker

Tags: werewolv.es

Did you make it past that heading...ok. So what would happen if a role blocker (say courtesan) tries to block another role blocker such as a dire wolf while other (DW is blocking them(court) on same night. Would it bounce and do nothing, they both get message, does one over power other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles that can role block (Direwolf, Courtesan) are immune to being role-blocked; as such, both "blocks" would go ahead and both players would receive a message informing them that they were blocked but would be otherwise unaffected.

Source, h2p:

**Courtesan:**

> If the Courtesan is blocked by another role-blocker, they will receive the normal "You were role-blocked last night" message, but the block will have no effect.

**Direwolf:**

> If the Direwolf is blocked by another role-blocker, they will receive the normal "You were role-blocked last night" message, but the block will have no effect.