# Blocker not blocked by a Blocker, but Blocker blocked by a Blocking Item - follow up question!

Tags: werewolv.es

As a follow up to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/352086/144891), although Blockers can't be blocked by another Blocker (but they still get the block message), can Blockers be blocked by Blocking Items, such as the Disruption Orb and the Potion of Weakness?  Can night-immune roles (Succ/Djinn) that are not normally affected by a Blocker's block also be *actually* blocked by the items?

I think I was playing Court and someone threw the Disruption Orb at me, and so couldn't block that night, ironically. Presumably the Pot of Weakness works in the same way.

So an item can block a Blocker, but a Blocker cannot block a Blocker? >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into this and the answer is apparently, yes - items can block a role blocker!

(This was news to me also)

Comment: *giggles* 

This was ext-318, so it was a very short-lived problem anyway!